# .Net Framework corrupted

Tags: .net-3.5, wcf

We are facing a problem of .Net framework corruption for one our clients with the following environment:

- OS : Windows 2008 Server SP2;
- Framework : .NET Framework 3.5 SP1;

Application Details

- Database : SQL Server 2008;
- Server : WCF hosted webservice;
- Client : WPF based UI;

Problem: The Config files inside the `..\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` are suddenly deleted and and not able to work with my application. Not able to repair .NET / Run SQL Server. The only option is to restore the earlier images versions of that machine

Any help is much appreciated

sam

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use the [.net cleanup tool and user guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/pages/8904493.aspx)

Edit: This tool removes any version of the .NET framework from 1.0 -> 3.5, inclusive of service packs. As Aaron's blog states, "It will remove files, directories, registry keys and values and Windows Installer product registration information for the .NET Framework.  The tool is intended primarily to return your system to a known (relatively clean) state in case you are encountering .NET Framework installation, uninstallation, repair or patching errors so that you can try to install again."

Answer (score 0):

Kind of difficult questions... I'd start by applyng Microsoft Update, then scanning the server with a good antivirus.
Beyond that, we'd need more info.
And yes, more of a question for server fault.

Answer (score 0):

First: Make a backup of the current state.  Then, if possible, try to only restore the missing files from one of the older images (it should be possible to mount an image and access it like a harddisk). If your imaging solution doesn't allow that, restore the image to a spare disk and copy the files from there.